# Kernel panic when trying to install Lubuntu over Windows 7

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, lubuntu

I know that some had the same problem, but with different codes. I've been searching the internet to find a solution, but I couldn't find any.

I'm trying to install Lubuntu and I keep getting a kernel panic `not syncing: attempted to kill init! Exi code=0x00000009`. I know that it isn't my disk or the distro, because I tried with a DVD and Xubuntu and the same thing happened.

I'm trying to install Linux over my previous Windows 7 (not as dual boot. I plan to erase the entire disk and install just the Linux, as I don't need that Windows anymore. I already backed up my files, etc.) I want to live with this new OS and also to learn more of programming, Linux, etc.

I'm sure my hardware can run Lubuntu even though it's an old 32-bit computer (I'm running the 18.04 which supports x32) or if it's that it already has Windows 7 installed on the machine (though I don't think that this should've been a problem from what I searched).

[image: Photo of the error]

I can't even try it without installation. I can't do anything except boot to the basic main menu from Lubuntu (which is something at least, as with Xubuntu I couldn't even boot to the menu).

Comment: Any 18.04 Ubuntu *flavor*, i.e. derivatives like Lubuntu and Xubuntu are now out of standard support. Ubuntu Desktop and Server are still supported but Server is CLI only so something you probably don't want and the Desktop is likely too much for an old machine. Ubuntu no longer supports 32-bit. You'll have to choose from the rapidly dwindling set of distros that still support it like Debian.

Comment: I will try to download and install Debian so, it isn't the same as Ubuntu and that's sad though I fear that it will give kernel panics too and won't work. If I could install Lubuntu it would be the best, even if it's an old version, my machine isn't new but I wanted to try something more like Ubuntu but ok :)

Comment: Are you sure your system is not 64bit compatible? Is your hardware approximately 15+years old?

Comment: Please tell us the brand name and model number of 1. the computer and 2. of the CPU. It will tell us if it is really a 32-bit computer (because long ago some 64-bit computers were delivered with 32-bit Windows). - If a 64-bit computer, please try the current Lubuntu 20.04 LTS. If a 32-bit computer I would recommend Puppy Linux, for example [BionicPup32](https://puppylinux.com/download.html). It works well in old computers and is quite user friendly (but very different from Windows. I tested it in two 32-bit computers recently).

Comment: I used hardware as old as from 2003 to QA-test Lubuntu releases up to Lubuntu 19.04; however you've provided specificis as even in 2003 most desktop hardware was *amd64* (64-bit) with only laptops still *i386*. By 2005 laptops were *amd64* (intels are AMD64 too as AMD created the compatible x86_64 cpu). I'm writing this on a 2009 dell & am using Lubuntu *jammy* (what will be 22.04 on release). You've provided no specifics, nor ruled out user error (did you verify ISO -- https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 or write to media (match with the release..)

Comment: Intel Celeron CPU E3200 2.40GHz 2.39GHz, the RAM has been changed from 2GB to 4GB (though just 3GB are useful or something), I'll try to install Debian, but I fear that the same Kernel panic will happen, if it install, even if it isn't what I wanted (Ubuntu or Lubuntu), it will make me pretty happy :)

Comment: Your 800Mhz CPU (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42770/intel-celeron-processor-e3200-1m-cache-2-40-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html) should run a supported release; though if your machine is limited to 3GB b/c of BIOS limitation; extra RAM will be wasted.  Your CPU is same vintage as what I'm using currently (though a cheaper CPU than mine).  Debian is off-topic here (*despite many of us using it*) & I'll provide https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ on 18.04, Lubuntu's LTS manual can be found here https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/  (it covers Lubuntu 20.04 LTS currently).

Comment: Did you verify your ISO?   verify the write of the ISO to your media?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  applies to 18.04 and earlier releases only)  If either was faulty; kernel panic is an indication of that...  You can always verify the media write using other boxes; myself I boot it in two other boxes (*one of like hardware & one very different*); if it boots on those other two boxes with media verification completing the issue isn't media; but something specific to the box you want to install on....

Comment: I agree with guiverc and support his advice. Your CPU is 64-bit, so should run current Lubuntu 64-bit versions. 3 GB RAM is plenty for this flavour of Ubuntu.

Comment: I verified the ISOs indeed with 7zip and the hashes, I know it's off topic but just to say, debian installation kinda failed, no kernel panic, but black screen without loading :'(, I'll try now to install the most recent LTS version of Lubuntu, do y'all think that this may be caused because there's already a windows 7 installed on the PC?

Comment: I'm so sad, I want so much so much so much to use Linux, specially Ubuntu (though lightweight, so Lubuntu was chosen), but this Kernel panic thing is so hard to deal with, mainly because I don't know what's causing it, it's not the USB/DVD, it doesn't seem to be the ISO, and afaik the hardware supports Lubuntu I guess (I even downloaded the 32 bits at first, so it should've worked!), I'm fearful that I'll need to stick with win 7 till I buy a newer PC :/

Comment: I write hundreds (300+) of ISOs to thumb-drive media per year & know how *iffy* the procedure is & why validation of writes matter (about 5-8% fail in my experience - USB media is made to cost & imperfect, no validation is included to keep costs down unlike ssd/hdd's etc) which is why the validation procedures exist. If you wrote the ISO to media incorrectly, or with software intended for different versions - then kernel panic or problems are expected; you've not provided any specifics - so haven't ruled out user procedures as already stated. Having win7 on box makes no difference.

Comment: It can be a user error PBKAC, as I'm not very geek and never installed Linux before, I'm using Rufus to transfer the ISO to USB, I heard it works great but I'm not sure, if it keeps like that, I'll try other programs as written in the official manual, I'll try everything before I give up, I really want Linux :D

Comment: Downloaded Lubuntu 20.04 LTS and I clicked Start (there was no Install button but I guess that's normal?) and it didn't gave any kernel panic, it checked the files successfully and I can see the mouse already, I'm feeling happy, and it started, there's an app icon to install it, I'll try now, it's installing! Thank you all, if I was on my own I wouldn't know that my PC could handle the newer amd64 version, I can't express on words how happy I am, I don't know if it'll actually install but seems that it will, so I'm freaking happy, thank you all so f much!

Comment: FYI:  Rufus is very good as I understand it (*I've never used it; I use `mkusb` maintained by another Lubuntu member who's commented on this thread) but like all apps, it needs to change over time & version of `rufus` matters (Ubuntu ISOs change with time so the apps that write the ISOs need to follow those changes). I've already provided the LTS manual link, but again https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html

Comment: Solved everything, and it works, I was typing wrong pass to master key and had a problem but I discovered that the password characters doesn't shows and that ain't a bug, seems to be working now, removed my previous comment about it. Thanks again to everyone here who helped, it really made my day, actually my whole life from now on lol

Comment: Welcome as a Lubuntu user @CeliaC :-)